# Is $U$ a vector subspace of $k^n$ an irreducible affine variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Every vector subspace of $k^n$ is the kernel of some linear map so in particular is the affine variety defined by a set of linear equations. But are they irreducible?

Comment: What do you think? And why?

Comment: I don't know. Imagining $\mathbb{R}^3$, I cannot imagine decomposing a plane into finitely many curves (since every affine variety has a finite irreducible decomposition). So I guess yes, but I don't know why, or why not.

Comment: Find a set of equations for the subspace, and use the definition of being irreducible: is the ideal they generate prime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $m$ denotes the dimension of $U$, then $U \cong k^m$ (as vector spaces, a fortiori as varieties), and the affine space is irreducible.

Comment: But under this isomorphism, must an affine variety of $k^n$ contained in $U$ correspond to an affine variety of $k^m$?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Anyway, you only have to know (which is trivial) that linear maps are also polynomial maps.